# How to run windows server on macOS with apple silicon?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, windows-server, parallels

I'm trying to run Windows Server on macOS with Apple Silicon.

Parallels can't install any x86 versions(windows server don't have arm versions out in the wild, only for OEM) I tried installing it on UTM and run it on emulation, but I wasn't able to reach the installation.

I will welcome any solution :)

Comment: You already answered your own question, it's ARM or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. These three Parallels support articles explain why.

From [this article](https://kb.parallels.com/125343):

> Virtual machines created on Intel-based Mac computers have x86_64 CPU architecture that is fundamentally different from the Arm architecture.
> Software applications are heavily dependent on a computer's CPU architecture: an application that is compiled (created) for one architecture, cannot be easily run on another architecture.

From [this article](https://kb.parallels.com/125375):

> Microsoft no longer provides support for Windows 10 Arm. And as a result, Windows 10 is no longer supported in Parallels Desktop on Mac computers with Apple M-series chips. However, Windows 11 should be fully compatible with all applications that Windows 10 is compatible with.

And finally from [this article](https://kb.parallels.com/124223):

> Supported Guest Operating Systems (Mac with Apple M-series chip) Only Arm versions of operating systems are supported.

and

> Supported Guest Operating Systems (Mac with an Intel processor) Only x86 versions of operating systems are supported.

**To summarize:** Only ARM-compatible OSes can be run on Parallels running on the ARM-based M silicon, and only x86-compatible OSes can be run on Parallels running on Intel-based Apple chips.

Virtualization is dependent on the host CPU's architecture, and cannot emulate between the platforms.